# What is the equation for this kind of recursive sequence?

Tags: geometry

I am not good at describing things, so here are some pictures that help me describing the problem better.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically, you have a square with side whose length is `s`, and a number `n`, you divide `s` by `n`, then you construct length times `n` squares from the sides with the quotient as side length so that they do not overlap, you also construct the squares from the corners.

Then you divide the quotient by `n` and use the new quotient as side length, and construct a new layer of squares.

Rinse and repeat, until you have a certain number of layers.

I create the pictures using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from PIL import Image
from random import random

def spectrum_position(n):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError('`n` should be an integer')
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('`n` must be non-negative')
    n %= 1530
    if 0 <= n < 255:
        return (255, n, 0)
    elif 255 <= n < 510:
        return (510-n, 255, 0)
    elif 510 <= n < 765:
        return (0, 255, n-510)
    elif 765 <= n < 1020:
        return (0, 1020-n, 255)
    elif 1020 <= n < 1275:
        return (n-1020, 0, 255)
    elif 1275 <= n < 1530:
        return (255, 0, 1530-n)

def recursive_split(division, iterations, unit=1):
    length = unit
    divisions = 1
    total_count = 1
    total_length = unit
    area = unit**2
    color_start = random()*1530
    colors = [spectrum_position(round(color_start+382.5*i)) for i in range(4)]
    colors = ['#'+'{:06x}'.format(sum(a << b for a, b in zip(color, (16, 8, 0)))) for color in colors]
    colors = [(colors[0], colors[2]), (colors[1], colors[3])]
    levels = [{
        'length': length,
        'divisions': 1,
        'unit_area': area,
        'count': 1,
        'shapes': [{'position': (-unit/2, -unit/2), 'color': colors[0][0]}]
    }]
    half = unit/2
    for i in range(iterations-1):
        color_level = colors[(i + 1) % 2]
        length = length/division
        total_length = total_length + length * 2
        unit_area = length**2
        side = divisions*division
        count = (divisions*division+1)*4
        total_count += count
        area += unit_area*count
        divisions = (divisions*division)+2
        shapes = []
        min_x = -half - length
        for i in range(side+2):
            x = min_x + length * i
            y1 = half
            y2 = -half - length
            i1 = i % 2
            i2 = (i + 1) % 2 if not division % 2 else i1
            shapes.append({'position': (x, y1), 'color': color_level[i1]})
            shapes.append({'position': (x, y2), 'color': color_level[i2]})
        
        for i in range(1, side+1):
            y = half - length * i
            i1 = i % 2
            i2 = (i + 1) % 2 if not division % 2 else i1
            shapes.append({'position': (min_x, y), 'color': color_level[i1]})
            shapes.append({'position': (half, y), 'color': color_level[i2]})
        
        half = half+length
        levels.append({
            'length': length,
            'divisions': divisions,
            'unit_area': unit_area,
            'count': count,
            'shapes': shapes
        })
    return {'levels': levels, 'total_area': area, 'total_count': total_count, 'total_length': total_length}

def plot_split(division, iterations, length=1080, alpha=1, unit=1):
    data = recursive_split(division, iterations, unit)
    radius = data['total_length']/2
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(length/100, length/100), dpi=100, facecolor='black')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    for level in data['levels']:
        unit = level['length']
        for shape in level['shapes']:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle(shape['position'], unit, unit, color=shape['color'], fill=True, alpha=alpha))
    
    plt.xlim(-radius, radius)
    plt.ylim(-radius, radius)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    image = Image.frombytes('RGB', fig.canvas.get_width_height(), fig.canvas.tostring_rgb())
    plt.close(fig)
    return image
```

I am wondering what is the mathematical equation to calculate the total area and total count of squares from the number of divisions and number of iterations.

I was able to get this:

```
import json

def area_n_count(division, iterations):
    count = 1
    area = 1
    areas = [1]
    counts = [1]
    divisions = 1
    for i in range(iterations-1):
        count += (divisions*division+1)*4
        area += division**(-2*i-2)*(divisions*division+1)*4
        divisions = (divisions*division)+2
        counts.append(count)
        areas.append(area)
    return {'area': areas, 'count': counts}
```

```
In [128]: print(json.dumps(area_n_count(2, 16), indent=4))
{
    "area": [
        1,
        4.0,
        6.25,
        7.5625,
        8.265625,
        8.62890625,
        8.8134765625,
        8.906494140625,
        8.95318603515625,
        8.976577758789062,
        8.988285064697266,
        8.994141578674316,
        8.997070550918579,
        8.998535215854645,
        8.999267593026161,
        8.99963379278779
    ],
    "count": [
        1,
        13,
        49,
        133,
        313,
        685,
        1441,
        2965,
        6025,
        12157,
        24433,
        48997,
        98137,
        196429,
        393025,
        786229
    ]
}

In [129]: print(json.dumps(area_n_count(3, 16), indent=4))
{
    "area": [
        1,
        2.7777777777777777,
        3.567901234567901,
        3.8532235939643344,
        3.950769699740893,
        3.983556029738014,
        3.9945149132264914,
        3.9981712195918475,
        3.9993903600694694,
        3.9997967815274733,
        3.999932259935563,
        3.999977419914788,
        3.999992473297848,
        3.9999974910984957,
        3.999999163699411,
        3.9999997212331273
    ],
    "count": [
        1,
        17,
        81,
        289,
        929,
        2865,
        8689,
        26177,
        78657,
        236113,
        708497,
        2125665,
        6377185,
        19131761,
        57395505,
        172186753
    ]
}

In [130]: print(json.dumps(area_n_count(4, 16), indent=4))
{
    "area": [
        1,
        2.25,
        2.640625,
        2.7431640625,
        2.76910400390625,
        2.7756080627441406,
        2.777235269546509,
        2.777642145752907,
        2.777743869461119,
        2.7777693006792106,
        2.7777756585019233,
        2.7777772479587384,
        2.777777645323013,
        2.7777777446640863,
        2.777777769499355,
        2.777777775708172
    ],
    "count": [
        1,
        21,
        121,
        541,
        2241,
        9061,
        36361,
        145581,
        582481,
        2330101,
        9320601,
        37282621,
        149130721,
        596523141,
        2386092841,
        9544371661
    ]
}
```

But I am wondering what are the proper mathematical equations to calculate such numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to think about the total *area* first.

In fact, to make it even more simple, think, first, about the length of the side of the entire square first. Also, to keep things simple, I will assume here that the side of the innermost square is $1$ (if it is $s$, then just multiply all the results with $s$).

The first square has side $1$. The second constructed square has a side that is extended, on both sides, by $\frac 1n$. This means that the total side of the second square is $1 + \frac2n$.

The to get the third square, you will increase the side of the existing square by $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so the side will now be $1+\frac2n + \frac2{n^2}$.

In general, you might already see that the side of the $k$-th square will be

$$1 + \frac2n + \frac{2}{n^2} + \cdots + \frac2{n^{k-1}}$$

which can quickly be calculated since it is just slightly modified power sum. Indeed, if we define $\alpha = \frac1n$, then the expression above can be rewritten to

$$\begin{align}
1 + \frac2n + \frac{2}{n^2} + \cdots + \frac2{n^{k-1}} &= 1 + 2\alpha + 2\alpha^2 +\cdots + 2\alpha^{k-1}\\
&=-1 + 2 + 2\alpha + 2\alpha^2 +\cdots + 2\alpha^{k-1} \\
&= -1 + 2\left(\alpha^0 + \alpha^1 + \cdots + \alpha^{k-1}\right)\\
&= -1 + 2\cdot \frac{1-\alpha^k}{1-\alpha}\\
&= -1 + 2\cdot\frac{1-\frac1{n^k}}{1-\frac1n}\\
&= -1 + 2\cdot \frac{n^k - 1}{n^k - n^{k-1}}
\end{align}$$

and the total area is simply the square of that value.

---

To calculate the count of squares of a given size, it's better to think of the total number of squares on *one* of the sides of the square. You have two options.

**Option 1**:

Calculating a recursive relation. Let's say that the number of squares on one side at layer $k$ is $a_k$. Then, clearly, $a_1=0$, since you start off with one square.

To get to the next layer, you need to split each square of the previous layer into $n$ squares, and then add two squares at the corners. This gives you the recursive relation

$$a_{k+1} = n\cdot a_k + 2$$ which you can solve with standard methods.

---

**Option 2**:

But, we can be more clever than that. We already know what the side of the $k$-th layer will be, it will be $S=-1 + 2\cdot \frac{n^k - 1}{n^k - n^{k-1}}$. And we also know that the $k$-th layer will be split into squares with side $s=\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}$.

And we also know that $S = a_k \cdot s$, so we can calculate $a_k$ directly from $S$ and $s$.

Comment: What about the count of squares?

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος See edit.